# Openstack project create exits with a error

Tags: installation, openstack

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Openstack Newton. I followed the guide from Openstack Documentation. But when I reach the step where I am supposed to create a Openstack project .

```
openstack project create --domain default   --description "Service Project" service -v
```

It is exiting with error.

```
START with options: [u'project', u'create', u'--domain', u'default' u'--description', u'Service Project', u'service', u'-v']
command: project create -> openstackclient.identity.v3.project.CreateProject
Using auth plugin: password
An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-856f08ea-f6d2-44c5-9042-eb6b64539847)
END return value: 1
```

**EDIT**:

I executed the same command with a Debug flag and this is the output.

```
START with options: [u'project', u'create', u'--domain', u'default',u'--description', u'Service Project', u'service', u'--debug']
options: Namespace(access_key='', access_secret='***', access_token='***', access_token_endpoint='', access_token_type='', auth_type='', auth_url='http://controller:35357/v3', authorization_code='', cacert=None, cert='', client_id='', client_secret='***', cloud='', consumer_key='', consumer_secret='***', debug=True, default_domain='default', default_domain_id='', default_domain_name='', deferred_help=False, discovery_endpoint='', domain_id='', domain_name='', endpoint='', identity_provider='', identity_provider_url='', insecure=None, interface='', key='', log_file=None, old_profile=None, openid_scope='', os_beta_command=False, os_compute_api_version='', os_identity_api_version='3', os_image_api_version='', os_network_api_version='', os_object_api_version='', os_project_id=None, os_project_name=None, os_volume_api_version='', passcode='', password='***', profile=None, project_domain_id='', project_domain_name='default', project_id='', project_name='admin', protocol='', redirect_uri='', region_name='', timing=False, token='***', trust_id='', url='', user_domain_id='', user_domain_name='default', user_id='', username='admin', verbose_level=3, verify=None)
Auth plugin password selected
auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'compute_api_version': u'2', 'key': None, u'database_api_version': u'1.0', u'interface': None, 'auth_url': 'http://controller:35357/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], u'image_api_version': u'2', 'verify': True, u'dns_api_version': u'2', u'object_store_api_version': u'1', 'username': 'admin', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': '', 'api_timeout': None, u'baremetal_api_version': u'1', 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', 'debug': True, u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', u'orchestration_api_version': u'1', 'timing': False, 'password': 'wasd', 'cacert': None, u'key_manager_api_version': u'v1', u'metering_api_version': u'2', 'deferred_help': False, u'identity_api_version': '3', u'volume_api_version': u'2', 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', u'container_api_version': u'1', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
defaults: {u'auth_type': 'password', u'compute_api_version': u'2', 'key': None, u'database_api_version': u'1.0', 'api_timeout': None, u'baremetal_api_version': u'1', u'image_api_version': u'2', 'cacert': None, u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', u'orchestration_api_version': u'1', u'interface': None, u'network_api_version': u'2', u'image_format': u'qcow2', u'key_manager_api_version': u'v1', u'metering_api_version': u'2', 'verify': True, u'identity_api_version': u'2.0', u'volume_api_version': u'2', 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', u'container_api_version': u'1', u'dns_api_version': u'2', u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
cloud cfg: {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'compute_api_version': u'2', u'orchestration_api_version': u'1', u'database_api_version': u'1.0', 'timing': False, 'auth_url': 'http://controller:35357/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], u'image_api_version': u'2', 'verify': True, u'dns_api_version': u'2', u'object_store_api_version': u'1', 'username': 'admin', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': '', 'api_timeout': None, u'baremetal_api_version': u'1', 'auth': {'username': 'admin', 'project_name': 'admin', 'user_domain_name': 'default', 'auth_url': 'http://controller:35357/v3', 'password': '***', 'project_domain_name': 'default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'container_api_version': u'1', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, u'interface': None, 'password': '***', 'cacert': None, u'key_manager_api_version': u'v1', u'metering_api_version': u'2', 'deferred_help': False, u'identity_api_version': '3', u'volume_api_version': u'2', 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
compute API version 2, cmd group openstack.compute.v2
network API version 2, cmd group openstack.network.v2
image API version 2, cmd group openstack.image.v2
volume API version 2, cmd group openstack.volume.v2
identity API version 3, cmd group openstack.identity.v3
object_store API version 1, cmd group openstack.object_store.v1
neutronclient API version 2, cmd group openstack.neutronclient.v2
Auth plugin password selected
auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'compute_api_version': u'2', 'key': None, u'database_api_version': u'1.0', u'interface': None, 'auth_url': 'http://controller:35357/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], u'image_api_version': u'2', 'verify': True, u'dns_api_version': u'2', u'object_store_api_version': u'1', 'username': 'admin', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': '', 'api_timeout': None, u'baremetal_api_version': u'1', 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', 'debug': True, u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', u'orchestration_api_version': u'1', 'timing': False, 'password': 'wasd', 'cacert': None, u'key_manager_api_version': u'v1', u'metering_api_version': u'2', 'deferred_help': False, u'identity_api_version': '3', u'volume_api_version': u'2', 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', u'container_api_version': u'1', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
command: project create -> openstackclient.identity.v3.project.CreateProject
Using auth plugin: password
Using parameters {'username': 'admin', 'project_name': 'admin', 'user_domain_name': 'default', 'auth_url': 'http://controller:35357/v3', 'password': '***', 'project_domain_name': 'default'}
Get auth_ref
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://controller:35357/v3 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: osc-lib keystoneauth1/2.12.1 python-requests/2.10.0 CPython/2.7.12"
Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller
"GET /v3 HTTP/1.1" 200 250
RESP: [200] Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 09:19:47 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Vary: X-Auth-Token X-Distribution: Ubuntu x-openstack-request-id: req-b9223d75-3b3e-4fed-a265-8c6d5278e23b Content-Length: 250 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/json 
RESP BODY: {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2016-10-06T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}], "id": "v3.7", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:35357/v3/", "rel": "self"}]}}

Making authentication request to http://controller:35357/v3/auth/tokens
"POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1" 401 114
Request returned failure status: 401
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-e130cf4c-4f89-43fa-a470-639478ef19ef)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliff/app.py", line 380, in run_subcommand
    self.prepare_to_run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 434, in prepare_to_run_command
    self.client_manager.auth_ref
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/clientmanager.py", line 198, in auth_ref
    self._auth_ref = self.auth.get_auth_ref(self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 181, in get_auth_ref
    return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 167, in get_auth_ref
    authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 675, in post
    return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/session.py", line 40, in request
    resp = super(TimingSession, self).request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 570, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-e130cf4c-4f89-43fa-a470-639478ef19ef)
clean_up CreateProject: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-e130cf4c-4f89-43fa-a470-639478ef19ef)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 135, in run
    ret_val = super(OpenStackShell, self).run(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliff/app.py", line 267, in run
    result = self.run_subcommand(remainder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 180, in run_subcommand
    ret_value = super(OpenStackShell, self).run_subcommand(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliff/app.py", line 380, in run_subcommand
    self.prepare_to_run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 434, in prepare_to_run_command
    self.client_manager.auth_ref
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/clientmanager.py", line 198, in auth_ref
    self._auth_ref = self.auth.get_auth_ref(self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 181, in get_auth_ref
    return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 167, in get_auth_ref
    authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 675, in post
    return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osc_lib/session.py", line 40, in request
    resp = super(TimingSession, self).request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 570, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-e130cf4c-4f89-43fa-a470-639478ef19ef)

END return value: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a script (credentials.sh) with following variables:

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=<ADMIN-PASS-HERE>
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://identityHost:5000/v3
```

Source the script

**source credentials.sh**

now execute your **openstack project create** command

Comment: I have tried this but it still throws the same error. Also the keystone table in the database is empty and I can't get the keystone_manage dbsync command to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

After installation, need to bootstrap firstly.
Have you run similar instructions?
For example, issue following commands,

```
keystone-manage bootstrap --bootstrap-password ADMIN_PASS \  
  --bootstrap-admin-url http://controller:35357/v3/ \  
  --bootstrap-internal-url http://controller:35357/v3/ \  
  --bootstrap-public-url http://controller:5000/v3/ \  
  --bootstrap-region-id RegionOne
```

Then try again.

Comment: @Ahmed Ashour Thanks for helping me formatting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue - turns out that I had a typo in my keystone.conf file.

I found this by going through all the configuration steps and confirming that I had setup everything correctly.